# JSP Page is not processing while called through AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsp

I have the following
1) Site A where the JSP Code which has to perform the following tasks.
   a) Print requet.getCookies() values
   b) Update the div tag using javascript function
2) Site B has a JSP Code from which the Site A jsp is called using AJAX.

Expected behaviour is to perform the tasks mentioned in 1st step.
Result what I am getting is the html code with request object as null
and no update to div tag.

Can  anyone please advise what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]."_

Answer (score 0):

Are you seeing any error in console of browser indicating cross origin ajax content cannot be loaded?

Usually cross origin (site a and b in your case) ajax call is not allowed unless you make site a to be let loaded from site b by adding certain headers to your response of site a jsp. These headers are called cors headers.Try adding following header to site a jsp .

Access-Control-Allow-Origin = url of site b

This will indicate the browser that site a let's its content loaded from a page that belongs to site b

Comment: Thanks Abhijith for your reply. I had added the following code in Site A jsp page and it is not loading at all.                                                                         <%=response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","www1.dev.com")%>

Comment: While Inspecting what I found is, it says Server 500 ERROR. we have enabled CORS in site A to be able to hit from Site B.

Comment: If I give simple scriptlet <%=suresh"%> , this is getting printed, whereas <%=request.getCookies()%> doesnt get printed

Comment: Have you started getting 500 after adding setheader code? Note that it should not be added as expression ie, it should be scriptlet.use the code inside <℅ ℅> and not inside <%= ℅>

Comment: <% response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","www1.de‌​v.com")%>